# Binary Search Tree recursive add

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to make a recursive add for my BST. The public add method takes an int argument, the private method takes the same int and a Node. This is the code I have so far

```
 public void add(int i) {

    add(i, root);

}

private void add(int i, Node n) {
    if (root==null){
        root=new Node(i);
    }

    if (i < n.element) {
        if (n.left != null) {
            add(i, n.left);
        } else {
            n.left = new Node(i);
        }
    } else if (i > n.element) {
        if (n.right != null) {
            add(i, n.right);
        } else {
            n.right = new Node(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I constanly keep getting null pointers, tried debugging as well but there's something flawed in my logic that I can't see.

Comment: In your `add` method you reference `root` while it should probably be the parameter `n` instead

Comment: Taking a step back may be the way

https://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/are-you-one-of-the-10-percent/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your tree is empty (root=null), you correctly create a new node and assign it to your `root` variable. But that's all it should do.
Therefore:

```
if (root==null){
    root=new Node(i);
    return; // DONE!!
}
```

Or, if you want:

```
if (root==null){
    root=new Node(i);
}
else if (i < n.element) {
....
```

Comment: Think it did the trick, doe my usage of the print method was wrong as well, so I'm not sure which did the trick, but kudos to You!